# Async execution of shell command not working properly

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, asynchronous, nstask, nsfilehandle

So, this is my code :

```
- (void)runCmd:(NSString *)cmd withArgs:(NSArray *)args
{
    NSLog(@"\nRunning ::\n\tCmd : %@\n\tArgs : %@",cmd, args);
    [theSpinner start];
    if (task)
    {
        [task interrupt];

    }
    else
    {
        task = [[NSTask alloc] init];
        [task setLaunchPath:cmd];

        [task setArguments:args];

        [pipe release];

        pipe = [[NSPipe alloc] init];
        [task setStandardOutput:pipe];

        NSFileHandle* fh = [pipe fileHandleForReading];

        NSNotificationCenter* nc;

        nc = [NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter];
        [nc removeObserver:self];
        [nc addObserver:self 
               selector:@selector(dataReady:) 
                   name:NSFileHandleReadCompletionNotification 
                 object:fh];
        [nc addObserver:self selector:@selector(dataAvailable:) name:NSFileHandleDataAvailableNotification object:fh];
        [nc addObserver:self 
               selector:@selector(taskTerminated:) 
                   name:NSTaskDidTerminateNotification 
                 object:task];

        [task launch];
        [fh readInBackgroundAndNotify];
    }
}

- (void)dataAvailable:(NSNotification*)n
{
    NSLog(@"Data Available : %@",n);
}

- (void)dataReady:(NSNotification*)n
{
    NSData* d;

    d = [[n userInfo] valueForKey:NSFileHandleNotificationDataItem];

    NSLog(@"Data Ready : %@",n);

    if ([d length])
    {
        NSLog(@"Data Ready : %@",[[NSString alloc] initWithData:d encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]);
    }
}

- (void) taskTerminated:(NSNotification*)note
{
    NSLog(@"Task Terminated : %@",note);
    [task release];
    task = nil;
    [theSpinner stop];

    NSAlert *alert = [[[NSAlert alloc] init] autorelease];
    [alert setMessageText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Command finished"]];

    [alert runModal];
}
```

I've tried running a command (e.g. the php interpreter at `/usr/bin/php`) with arguments (e.g. the file to be interpreted by php `test.php`).

The thing is :

- The script runs fine
- BUT, I'm receiving a `Data Ready` and `Task    Terminated`
  notification BEFORE I've managed to get all the output.    (I mean,
  the `dataReady:` function fetches just the first part of the
  output and the rest of it is nowhere to be found...)

**I basically want to be reading, asynchronously, all output - WHILE the command is running.**

Any Ideas? What am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You use `readInBackgroundAndNotify` to schedule your reading. This method reads only one buffer full of data and notifies. You either need to call `readInBackgroundAndNotify` in your notification method again to read more data or you need to use `readToEndOfFileInBackgroundAndNotify` if you want to receive all the data at once.

Comment: Absolutely correct. (Just figured out it myself, btw, but thanks a lot anyway! ;-))

Answer (score 1):

There's a new API since 10.7, so you can avoid using NSNotifications.

```
task.standardOutput = [NSPipe pipe];
[[task.standardOutput fileHandleForReading] setReadabilityHandler:^(NSFileHandle *file) {
    NSData *data = [file availableData]; // this will read to EOF, so call only once
    NSLog(@"Task output! %@", [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]);

    // if you're collecting the whole output of a task, you may store it on a property
    [self.taskOutput appendData:data];
}];
```

IMPORTANT:

When your task terminates, you have to set readabilityHandler block to nil; otherwise, you'll encounter high CPU usage, as the reading will never stop.

```
[task setTerminationHandler:^(NSTask *task) {

    // do your stuff on completion

    [task.standardOutput fileHandleForReading].readabilityHandler = nil;
    [task.standardError fileHandleForReading].readabilityHandler = nil;
}];
```