# echo Does Not Work with NSTask and readInBackgroundAndNotify

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, echo, nstask, nsfilehandle

I have the following Obj-C code and its log output. Can anyone tell me why I'm not getting any output from the NSFileHandle?

```
@implementation AppDelegate

- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification {
    [self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(startTask:) withObject:nil];
}

- (void) startTask: (id) sender
{
    NSPipe *pipe = [[NSPipe alloc] init];
    NSFileHandle *fh = pipe.fileHandleForReading;

    [fh readInBackgroundAndNotify];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(output:) name:NSFileHandleReadCompletionNotification object:fh];

    NSTask *echoTask = [[NSTask alloc] init];

    echoTask.standardOutput = pipe;
    echoTask.standardError = [[NSPipe alloc] init];
    echoTask.launchPath = @"/bin/echo";
    echoTask.arguments = @[@"hello world!"];

    NSLog(@"launching...");
    [echoTask launch];
    [echoTask waitUntilExit];
    NSLog(@"finished.");
}

- (void) output:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    NSFileHandle *fh = notification.object;
    NSLog(@"fh: %@", fh);

    NSString *output = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:[fh readDataToEndOfFile] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    NSLog(@"output: '%@'", output);
}

@end
```

log:

```
2014-12-16 10:19:58.154 SubProcess2[14893:704393] launching...
2014-12-16 10:19:58.165 SubProcess2[14893:704393] fh: <NSConcreteFileHandle: 0x6080000e9e80>
2014-12-16 10:19:58.165 SubProcess2[14893:704393] output: ''
2014-12-16 10:19:58.166 SubProcess2[14893:704393] finished.
```

If I do it synchronously or using the approach in https://stackoverflow.com/a/16274541/1015200 I could get it to work.
Any other techniques and variations(such as launching task without performSelectorInBackground) have failed.
I really want to see if I can get it to work using the notification.
So if I can get any help that'd be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data that has already been read is passed to the notification in the `userInfo` dictionary under the key `NSFileHandleNotificationDataItem`, you should be accessing that and not attempting to read further data. E.g. something like:

```
- (void) output:(NSNotification *)notification
{
   NSString *output = [[NSString alloc]
                      initWithData:notification.userInfo[NSFileHandleNotificationDataItem] 
                          encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

   NSLog(@"output: '%@'", output);
}
```

HTH